# convert html to pdf file using wkhtmltopdf in a single command

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I have some html files as :

1.html, 2.html, 3.html

I want to convert it into 1.pdf, 2.pdf and 3.pdf

Currently I am usingthe below command to convert this html file to pdf files manually one by one using :

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe 1.html 1.pdf
wkhtmltopdf.exe 2.html 2.pdf
wkhtmltopdf.exe 3.html 3.pdf
```

How to convert all these html files into pdf in a single go.

Comment: `for /L %i in (1,1,3) do wkhtmltopdf.exe %%i.html %%i.pdf`

Comment: @Ronak Which shell are you using?

Comment: `for /F %i in ('dir /b *.html') do wkhtmltopdf.exe %%i %%i.pdf`

Comment: am using windows syste. So, running these command from dos prompt. Actually I have tried in bulk using a shell script also. But currently am on windows environment.